# Script php that search files

Tags: php, file, search, drupal-7

I'm working on a project using Drupal7 that uploads PDF files into a directory,
and was wondering if there is a PHP script that allows me to search in the uploaded files.
For example, if I write in the search box "JAVA", it will return all the files that have the "JAVA" as part of the content.

Answer (score 0):

```
function searchFiles($needle, $haystack){
    $found = array();
    $FILES = scandir($haystack);
    foreach($FILES as $FILE){
        if("." === substr($FILE, 0, 1)) continue;
        try{
            $content = file_get_contents($haystack."/".$FILE);
            if(strpos($content, $needle) !== false) array_push($found, $FILE);
        }catch(Exception $e){}
    }
    return $found;
}

$files = searchFiles("some text", "/var/www/html/");
```

---

Here's a bash script that will do it without PHP. Upload it to your server then `chmod +x` it so you can run it. you can then call the script from php with exec.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Recursively searches the all text files in the current working directoy
# for a given pattern. Search is case-insensitive and regex may be used in the patteren.
# Matches are highlighted.
# Usage: $ lazygrep "somepattern"

PATTERN=$1
DIRSS=$(pwd)
clear
printf "\n\nSEARCHING FOR $PATTERN IN $DIRSS\n\n"
grep -inIEr --color=ALWAYS "$PATTERN" $DIRSS
printf "\n\n"
```

Comment: thank you for your comment, but im getting all this warnings:   
Warning: is_dir(): Unable to find the wrapper "public" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in file_prepare_directory()(.....)
Warning: is_dir(): Unable to find the wrapper "public" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in file_prepare_directory()(.....)
Warning: is_dir(): Unable to find the wrapper "public" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in file_prepare_directory()(.....)

Comment: Warning: is_dir(): Unable to find the wrapper "public" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in file_prepare_directory()(.....) Warning: is_dir(): Unable to find the wrapper "public" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in file_prepare_directory()(.....) Warning: is_dir(): Unable to find the wrapper "public" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in file_prepare_directory()(.....)  

I think because of this :  $filepath="public://";
  $url=file_create_url($filepath);
  $files = searchFiles("some text", $url);